# How to get the screen of a window with XCB?

Tags: xcb

In Xlib, XWindowAttributes structure contains a pointer to the screen that the window is on. But in the corresponding structure of XCB (xcb_get_window_attributes_reply_t), there is no such member.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to get the screen of a window.

What you can do is find the root window ancestor of your window, then iterate over all the screens until you find the one owning your root.

Answer (score 3):

```
xcb_screen_t* screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(connection)).data;
```

you should read this tutorial http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/

Comment: But how if there are multiple screens and the windows of a connection are not in the same one?

Comment: I don't know. I just started learning X11. Maybe you find something in the X11 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As @peoro pointed out, you should first get the root window of the screen containing the window, and then loop through all the screens until you found the one that matches the previous mentioned root window id.

Here's an example:

```c
/* compile: cc main.c -o main -lxcb */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xproto.h>

int
main(void)
{
    xcb_connection_t *conn;
    xcb_window_t window;
    xcb_get_geometry_cookie_t geometry_cookie;
    xcb_get_geometry_reply_t *geometry_reply;
    xcb_screen_t *screen;
    xcb_screen_iterator_t it;

    /* put the id of the window here */
    window = 0x1000002;
    conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    geometry_cookie = xcb_get_geometry_unchecked(conn, window);
    geometry_reply = xcb_get_geometry_reply(conn, geometry_cookie, NULL);
    it = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(conn));

    for (screen = it.data; it.rem != 0; xcb_screen_next(&it), screen = it.data) {
        if (screen->root == geometry_reply->root) {
            printf("window %lu found on screen with %hux%hu dimensions\n",
                window, screen->width_in_pixels, screen->height_in_pixels);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(geometry_reply);
    xcb_disconnect(conn);

    return 0;
}
```